# Split my data based on a condition

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data which is to be splited into two sets such as i need data points below 146 in one set and above 146 in another set. the original data set is

```
dat <- c(208.3, 357.63, 238.06, 227.91, 231.79, 275.43, 241.27, 163.39, 
         160.31, 255.23, 214.74, 209.92, 160.32, 222.22, 133.8, 240.94, 
         147.46, 251.53, 165.07, 129.26, 149.4, 143.79, 249.73, 183.93, 
         252.03, 288.49, 208.29, 297.48, 208.97, 378.35, 153.96, 134.6, 
         370, 278.91, 290.48, 241.74, 224.41, 402.15, 284.57, 370.73, 
         266.67, 408.67, 164.09, 234.94, 206.94, 363.85, 208.11, 327.58, 
         213.55, 241.04, 216.4, 213.98, 276.65, 165.56, 243.86, 239.57, 
         266.16, 195.99, 185.05, 309.52, 399.34, 296.51, 192.39, 293.18, 
         212.11, 273.34, 134.18, 258.13, 221.16, 313.82, 214.37, 303.43, 
         233.79, 225.39, 211.06, 266.59, 177.92, 205.18, 190.18, 288.33, 
         207.09, 306.67, 240.01, 219.11, 195.42, 333.76, 190.28, 236.32, 
         214.03, 264.94, 228.61, 226.3, 206.24, 253.57, 233.92, 340.87, 
         217.67, 253.01, 209.19, 265.51)
```

Comment: welcome to SO. It is much easier for others to work with the data you offer if you use `dput()`

Answer (score 1):

```
data <- 136:156
set1 <- data[data<146]
set2 <- data[data>146]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is just a vector (which it looks like from the above):

```
# Example data
your_data <- seq(from = 1, to = 300, by = 3)

# Vector of data below the threshold 
below_146 <- your_data[which(your_data < 146)]

# Vector of data above the threshold 
above_146 <- your_data[which(your_data > 146)]
```

Note that neither subset will include values that exactly equal 146.

Answer (score 1):

You can get them in a list:

```
lst <- split(dat, dat<146)
```